# Yii2 Masked input negative numbers

Tags: php, regex, yii2, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I have problem with Yii 2 MaskedInput. I need have mask for year range e.g. 1995-2008. My question is how to date range add option to negative e.g. -32-2015 .... please help with regexp.

Where:

- minus is optional
- min number is 1 and max 4 eg. -10-2015
- and between years is dash

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute' => 'DATE_RANGE',
    'format' => 'html',
    'filter' => \yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget([
        'name' => 'FindingAidSearch[DATE_RANGE]',
        'mask' => '9999-9999',
        'value' => $searchModel->DATE_RANGE,
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'e.g. 1980-2000',
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ]
    ]),
    'value' => function($model){
        return Html::encode($model->DATE_RANGE);
    }
],
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just parse (convert) the string to a number and check the numeric value in a simple test?

Comment: I do not understand. Please add some example of numbers that are to considered valid and examples of invalid numbers.

Comment: Not related to the question, but sorry for the excessive number of edits from me. This text created a Markdown ambiguity which I didn't know how to handle. Had to research to find a proper way of formatting code after a list.

Comment: @AdrianHHH i need basic year range 2000-2010 but i must this year range have in negative years. Between year -xxxx to xxxx eg. -2400 - 2015.

Comment: @Thomas Please [edit] the question to show several sets of valid and several more sets of invalid numbers. The words in your last comment do not explain, to me, what you want.